# PDF won't open from .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, tkinter, popen

my program uses subprocess.Popen to open pdf files. it works when i run the .py script, but when i convert the script to a .exe, and then try to open the pdf's using the .exe, the pdf's no longer open. in fact, after the .exe is run, NO pdf's on my machine open, even if i try to open one from my desktop.

```
# import _tkinter

import PyPDF2
import os
import json
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess




class FileLabels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_widgets = []

    def create_label(self, filename):
        new_label = tk.Label(text=filename)
        new_label.grid(row=6+found_files.index(filename), column=1)
        self.all_widgets.append(new_label)

    def create_copy_button(self, filename):
        new_button = tk.Button(text="Open", command=lambda: openfile(filename))
        new_button.grid(row=6+found_files.index(filename), column=2)
        self.all_widgets.append(new_button)

file_labels = FileLabels()

def openfile(filename):
    path = f'{directory}\{filename}'
    subprocess.Popen([path], shell=True)

def external_get_folder():
    global folder_entry
    global start_window
    start_window = tk.Tk()
    start_window.title("BSP PDF Searcher")
    folder_label = tk.Label(text="1. Copy paste all PDF's into a folder on your computer.\n"
                                 "2. Copy paste the folder location here and click OK.\n"
                                 "Get some coffee. This may take a few minutes.")
    folder_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
    folder_entry = tk.Entry()
    folder_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    folder_button = tk.Button(text="OK", command=lambda: external_extract_pdf(widgets))
    folder_button.grid(row=2, column=2)
    widgets = []
    start_window.mainloop()

def external_extract_pdf(widgets):
    for i in widgets:
        i.destroy()
    global directory
    global search_entry
    global drawing_contents
    global files_in_folder
    global damaged
    try:
        directory = folder_entry.get()
    except _tkinter.TclError:
        pass

    #create dictionary of contents
    damaged = []
    files_in_folder = 0
    drawing_contents = {}

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        with open(f, "rb") as pdf_file:
            try:
                read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                files_in_folder += 1
            number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
            page = read_pdf.pages[0]
            try:
                page_content = page.extractText().lower()
            except IndexError:
                damaged.append(filename)
            else:
                drawing_contents[filename] = page_content
    display_results()

def display_results():
    global search_entry
    global search_button
    try:
        start_window.destroy()
    except _tkinter.TclError:
        pass

    results_window = tk.Tk()
    results_window.title("BSP PDF Searcher")
    dir_label = tk.Label(text=f"Searching in {directory}\n{files_in_folder} files, {len(damaged)} damaged")
    dir_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
    search_label = tk.Label(text="Enter words to search: ")
    search_label.grid(row=3,column=1)
    search_entry = tk.Entry()
    search_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)
    search_button = tk.Button(text="Search", command=lambda: ext_search(widgets))
    search_button.grid(row=3, column=3)
    try:
        x = found_files_label
    except:
        found_files_label = tk.Label()
        found_count_label = tk.Label()
        widgets = []


def ext_search(widgets):
    global found_files_label
    global found_count_label
    global found_files

    for i in file_labels.all_widgets:
        i.destroy()

    try:
        found_count_label.destroy()
    except NameError:
        pass


    key_words_list = list(search_entry.get().split(" "))
    for i in widgets:
        i.destroy()
    found_count = 0
    found_files = []
    for filename, contents in drawing_contents.items():
        if all(i in contents for i in key_words_list):
            found_files.append(filename)
            found_count += 1

    for i in found_files:
        file_labels.create_label(i)
        file_labels.create_copy_button(i)

    found_count_label = tk.Label(text=f"{found_count} results:")
    found_count_label.grid(row=4,column=1)




external_get_folder()
```

Comment: i believe i found the root of the problem, but still have no solution. due to the security settings on my machine, the .exe will only open if i run as administrator. when that happens, the program that's run by the adm account is trying to open a file from the non-adm account. any way to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried using `os.startfile` instead of `subprocess.Popen`? The `startfile` method will open whatever file you pass it in the system default app for that filetype.

Comment: @JRiggles thank you for your response. unfortunately i get the same result